# Logarithmic distribution

Tags: math, distribution, logarithm

First of all, math is not my area.

Imagine a problem like this:

I have a number of money to spend, say 500, and i need to spend them on a fixed number of days, say 20. I have a fixed maximum of money to spend per day, like 50. I don't need to spend money on a day.

Now i need to know how to calculate the total number of money I have to spend each day to get a spending curve like the following:

[image: Curve]

My goal is a function that takes a number of money and a number of days, and returns an tuple with day number and  ammount of money for that day.

I know i need to use logarithms of some type, and i've tried pretty much everything that my brain can handle. I've been looking at [wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingLogarithmic.html) and this formula:

y = a + b ln x

But it does not really help me.

An hint or example in PHP, Python or C# would be great, but any language will do.

**PLEASE** let me know if you need any more information or if the question is vague, I really want to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: The algorithm you're shooting for is vague... if you have a maximum you can spend, then the line will be linear -- starting at 500 and going down 50 each day.  (`y = 500 - 50x`)  If you have no minimum, then the formula is simply `y = 500` since you are not required to spend at all before the last day.  The *actual* curve will fall somewhere between the two, but without an exact amount you must spend each day, there is really no way to plot this.

Comment: you should rather ask this question at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah I know if it sound vague, this is not my area at all. Is it easier if we say that i need to spend at least 1 money per day? @Andreas Niedermair you're probably right, i did consider that when i posted my question, but since it's in a programming context i decided to go with SO.

Comment: If you need to spend at least 1 then the boundary lines will be `y = 500 - 50x` and `y = 500 - x`.  You will be left with the area between the lines, which is where the actual spending might be.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you want a log distribution. A parabolic one will do to obtain the curve form you want:

```
 spend[day] = a day^2 + c
```

where:

```
a -> (6 * (TD - TA)) / (TD *(-1 - 3 * TD + 4 * TD^2))  


c -> -((1 + 3 * TD - 6*TA*TD + 2 * TD^2)/ (-1 - 3 * TD + 4 * TD^2))  

TA = Total Amount
TD = Total Days
```

With this the amount you spend the last day is 1.

For your example values:  (amt 500, days 20)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i definitely think that's what i want to achieve. Let me try this and come back.

Comment: What plotting library do you use? Looks neat.

Comment: @alexn It's Mathematica, from Wolfram. Nice but expensive :(  http://www.wolfram.com/

Comment: @alexn: I think Maxima + Gnuplot could achieve similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what you are asking for is not a linear equation?
For example
y=f(x)=-50x+500 and the total number of days would be x where y=0.